# Calling a ViewPart(SWT) from void main

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt

I am new to eclipse plugin and SWT. I am designing a view part with some functionalities.
But the only problem is that I have to Launch it as a eclipse plugin to check. 
Is there any way that we can call this from that main(String[] args) method?

I am posting my sample viewpart code

```
public class View extends ViewPart {
public static Display display=new Display();
public static final String ID = "Test.View"; //$NON-NLS-1$
private final FormToolkit toolkit = new FormToolkit(Display.getCurrent());

public View() {
}

/**
 * Create contents of the view part.
 * @param parent
 */
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    Composite container = toolkit.createComposite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    toolkit.paintBordersFor(container);
    {
        Label lblNewLabel = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(25, 46, 49, 13);
        toolkit.adapt(lblNewLabel, true, true);
        lblNewLabel.setText("New Label");
    }

    Spinner spinner = new Spinner(container, SWT.BORDER);
    spinner.setBounds(88, 105, 47, 21);
    toolkit.adapt(spinner);
    toolkit.paintBordersFor(spinner);

    DragSource dragSource = new DragSource(container, DND.DROP_MOVE);

    DropTarget dropTarget = new DropTarget(container, DND.DROP_MOVE);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(container, SWT.NONE);
    canvas.setBounds(94, 161, 174, 148);
    toolkit.adapt(canvas);
    toolkit.paintBordersFor(canvas);

    createActions();
    initializeToolBar();
    initializeMenu();
}

public void dispose() {
    toolkit.dispose();
    super.dispose();
}

/**
 * Create the actions.
 */
private void createActions() {
    // Create the actions
}

/**
 * Initialize the toolbar.
 */
private void initializeToolBar() {
    IToolBarManager tbm = getViewSite().getActionBars().getToolBarManager();
}

/**
 * Initialize the menu.
 */
private void initializeMenu() {
    IMenuManager manager = getViewSite().getActionBars().getMenuManager();
}

@Override
public void setFocus() {
    // Set the focus
}
```

Can I write something like

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    View v=new View();

    Shell shell=new Shell(display);
    v.createPartControl(shell);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Not really, Eclipse views are part of RCP and depend on a its infrastructure. You can create a small RCP application which only shows your view instead.
2. Having `public static Display display=new Display();` in your view is completely wrong! There is certainly a `Display` already by the time your code runs, which can be accessed by `Display.getDefault()` (on any thread) or `Display.getCurrent()` (on GUI thread).